# Union select without duplication | Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, union

this should be a simple question, but I find it quiet tough, I have two models: Amodel and Bmodel, and these models are related to two other models: Acompositions and Bcompositions containing attributes: aname anb bname.

Initially, I render the names in two tables, one for each model. For example for model A:

```
<% @amodel.acompositions.each do |acomposition| %>

  <tr>
    <td><%= Amodel.find(acomposition.amodel_id).aname %> </td>
  </tr>

<% end %>
```

Now I wanna do the same but using one only tab to render all the names, and I taught I can use a union without duplication between the two tabs. But I don't know how to do that given that the attributes don't have the same names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't be having `find` inside a view - it violates MVC principles.

Secondly, `Amodel.find(acomposition.amodel_id)` should be expressable as `acomposition.amodel` if you have set up your relationships properly (this looks like Acomposition `belongs_to :amodel`). (However, this confuses me... shouldn't the model pointed by `acomposition.amodel_id` be the very `@amodel` you had before? If it is not, something smells.) As it stands, this looks very inefficient.

So, what you can do is find all the Amodels and Bmodels in the controller, extract names, and smoosh up the resultant arrays. Without playing with your model relationships as I am not sure I understand them, you can do:

```
model_names =
  @amodel.acompositions.map { |acomposition|
    Amodel.find(acomposition.amodel_id).aname
  } +
  @bmodel.bcompositions.map { |bcomposition|
    Bmodel.find(bcomposition.bmodel_id).bname
  }
```

and then in your view just iterate over that.

If you can't do that, I strongly suggest you clarify your question (and include the relevant relationships).

Comment: Works perfectly ! with a ".uniq" in the end to  avoid duplication. And you're right about the find function, I'm trying to correct a bit. Thank you !